# Type of variable of JDBC Request in JMeter

Tags: java, string, jdbc, jmeter, typeconverter

I have a problem with my JMeter code, particularly with type of variables that are returned by JDBC Request.
This because then i have to make a json with this variables and therefore is most important the type of them otherwise my rest web service returns error.
I made this code:

[image]

[image]

The problem is on global_state variable because jdbc request save it as a string but the value is a float in my rest service.
What is the solution? 
I also tried to use Beanshell PreProcessor to convert it without any result.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it resolved, or won't fail during the http request, with this code:

```
"grid_voltage":  "${grid_voltage_1}"
```